# Is there a way to retrieve the inPoint time and outPoint time information in Adobe Audition using ExtendScript code?

Tags: adobe, extendscript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aky7W.png)

As in the image, I have a piece of code, but it retrieves the inPoint and outPoint incorrectly. Please help me.

I hope to be able to retrieve information about inPoint time and outPoint time.